# Protractor - Chromedriver error in azure devops pipeline

Tags: selenium, azure-devops, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

I am getting the following error in Azure Devops pipeline when running the protractor tests.
How can i fix this ?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7EcC.png)

Comment: Please avoid images when possible and take the proper time to format your question so that it's searchable, it will help people and help you.

Answer (score 0):

You should comment the selenium address in your config file. Then it will work.

// seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub', It is connecting to the local connection hence not working